# Organizing multiple IntelliJ projects with common modules

Tags: intellij-idea

We have a family of Java-based products which use common modules.  Typically, I just work on a single product at a time, and load all of the necessary modules into a project for that product.  This works nicely when I want to have IntelliJ help me with all of the interrelationships within the source code used by a particular product.  This is useful both for static analysis and debugging.

However, if I choose to work on multiple products simultaneously, and I have the same modules loaded in those project, I notice that IntelliJ seems to spend a lot of time re-indexing.  For example, if I modify the code in commonModule1, both Project1 and Project2 need to update their indices.

How can I organize my projects to limit re-indexing, while still allowing me to easily debug the common source?

Comment: What exactly changes when you update the code in the module? Do you produce jars and do the modules depend one on another via the jars?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - When I build with Maven, then we do produce jars (or wars).  A single module typically produces a single jar.  The higher level jars (or wars) depend on many lower level modules (jars).

Comment: You should consider using the module dependencies, with Maven that would be SNAPSHOT dependencies. In the same project  they will be resolved via the module sources instead of the jars.